# Add Active Navigation Class on asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I've this html code:

```
                  <ul id="main-nav">
                    <!-- Accordion Menu -->
                    <li><a href="" class="nav-top-item   /*i want to add class here*/">
                        <!-- Add the class "no-submenu" to menu items with no sub menu -->
                        Main link </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Service_Update.aspx">link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="ContactUS.aspx">link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="About.aspx">link 3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li></ul>
```

I want to add "current" class to tag --a--  when user click in Main link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#main-nav > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

If you need to remove the class from a link which was previously clicked, you can use the following:

```
$('#main-nav > li > a').click(function() {
    $('#main-nav a').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```